# How to convert a 3*2 figure in a PDF file to 2*3 Figure?

Tags: floats, pdf, subfloats

I have a PDF file where 6 figures in 3*2 forms are stored. I imported the pdf into my report, but it does not look good. So, I wanna convert it to 2*3. However, I don't have the source to recreate the figure. Is there any way to do it in LaTeX?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume you have the following document that has a figure with a 3 rows and 2 columns on page 10 (called `lipsum.pdf`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\sloppy
\lipsum[1-50]

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ c @{\qquad} c}
    \includegraphics[width=5em]{example-image-a} &
    \includegraphics[width=5em]{example-image-b} \\ \\
    \includegraphics[width=5em]{example-image-c} &
    \includegraphics[width=5em]{example-image-c} \\ \\
    \includegraphics[width=5em]{example-image-b} &
    \includegraphics[width=5em]{example-image-a}
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{A $3 \times 2$ collection figures, 2 per row, 3 per column.}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

Now include that single page only into a blank document with a grid overlay in `b`ig `p`oints (or `bp`s) provided by [`eso-pic`](//ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[grid,gridunit=bp]{eso-pic}

\begin{document}

\mbox{}% Just set something on the page

\AddToShipoutPictureFG*{% Add a picture to the ForeGround of this page only
  \AtPageLowerLeft{% At the lower left of the page
    \includegraphics[page=10]{lipsum}% Add page 10 of lipsum.pdf
  }%
}%

\end{document}
```

Now you can identify the `l`ower `l`eft and `u`pper `r`ight `x`, `y` coordinate (in `bp`) of a "`b`ounding `b`ox" for each image that you can extract using the `bb=bbllx bblly bburx bbury` key-value combination of `\includegraphics` from [`graphicx`](//ctan.org/pkg/graphicx). Then include the separate images into your document with a new arrangement (2 rows with 3 columns, say) by using the entire combination: `page`, `bb` (short for `b`ounding `b`ox) and `clip` keys:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\sloppy
\lipsum[1-50]

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ c @{\qquad} c @{\qquad} c }
    \includegraphics[page=10,bb=245 629 295 668,clip]{lipsum} &% Original row 1, column 1
    \includegraphics[page=10,bb=315 629 365 668,clip]{lipsum} &% Original row 1, column 2
    \includegraphics[page=10,bb=245 575 295 615,clip]{lipsum}% Original row 2, column 1
    \\ \\
    \includegraphics[page=10,bb=315 575 365 615,clip]{lipsum} &% Original row 2, column 2
    \includegraphics[page=10,bb=245 525 295 562,clip]{lipsum} &% Original row 3, column 1
    \includegraphics[page=10,bb=315 525 365 565,clip]{lipsum}% Original row 3, column 2
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{A $2 \times 3$ collection figures, 3 per row, 2 per column.}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Rotate the image 90 degrees while printing the image, by using the optional argument `angle` of `\includegraphics` command.

Comment: But this will rotate the individual images as well.  I doubt that is desirable.